# Set color for button field in blackberry using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How can I set the color for a button field in Blackberry using Java?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to create a Custom button . refer this link

http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/167